# Add Shibboleth SP to a tenant in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp, wso2-identity-server

I'm having a strange behaviour for this use case:
WSO2 IS with a tenant (tenant A) and a Shibboleth Service Provider added in the tenant (SaaS is NOT selected so the SP should be only visible to the tenant).
Shibboleth SP has the metadata of the wso2 IDP and certificates are in place and correct. Configurations are done via carbon console.
Navigating an URL protected by Shibboleth SP I get the strange behaviour:

I get redirected to the tenantDomain=carbon.super and (correctly) wso2 logs tell me that my SP is not registered.

TLDR: I cannot find a way to notify the tenantDomain in a SP initiated SSO between Shibboleth SP and WSO2 IS. Is this behaviour intended? thanks

here the wso2 IS resident IDP metadata. This was generated with the "download metadata" button in wso2 console. This was then copied in the Shibboleth SP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://iam01.com">
    <IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" validUntil="2019-01-24T14:47:48.803Z">
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://iam01.com:9443/samlsso" ResponseLocation="https://iam01.com:9443/samlsso"/>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://iam01.com:9443/samlsso"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://iam01.com:9443/samlsso"/>
    </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Comment: summoning @gusto2 , master of wso2 and Shibboleth !

Comment: Can you share the idp metadata file?

Comment: @farasath I just updated my question. Anyway, is this a covered use case? thanks

Comment: Is there a way to manually edit and upload the metadata file?
you can try changing the URLs from https://iam01.com:9443/samlsso to https://iam01.com:9443/samlsso?tenantDomain=tenantA.com and try out

Comment: thank you, it worked great!!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the URLs from 
iam01.com:9443/samlsso 
to 
iam01.com:9443/samlsso?tenantDomain=tenantA.com

in the SAML metadata document.